# Populating ComboBox With Object Property Using ObjectDataProvider

Tags: wpf, combobox, objectdataprovider

I have an *ObjectDataProvider* defined as follows:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="employeeDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type cbb2:EmployeeAccess}" MethodName="getEmployees">            
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

As you can see the method *getEmployees* is called which returns a list of type *Employee*. The Employee class is defined as follows:

```
class Employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML page has a combo box that I want to populate with the employee name. Here is what I have so far:

```
<ComboBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource employeeDataProvider}}"/>
```

The problem I am having is the combo box is being populated with the Employee object and not the name property of the Employee.

Here is a picture of what's happening:

[image: combo box]

My question is, how to I get the combo box to populate with just the name property of the employee?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this property to the combo box

```
DisplayMemberPath="name"
```

eg:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="name" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource employeeDataProvider}}"/>
```

Comment: Wow that was easy! I knew it was simple but I am so new to WPF (2 hours)!

Comment: Another quick question.. what if name was not defined as a property with get and set but rather with methods such as getName() and setName()? How would I access the name then?